# Does pressure decreases in accelerating fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Bernuolli says that in a pipe when speed **increases** pressure also **decreases** and that happen when pipe become **narrower**.

1. So,if a fluid  **accelerate** (increases speed) due to pressure difference in a pipe that **DO NOT** changes area and  **do not** become narrower, WILL THE PRESSURE STILL BE DECREASING DURING THIS ACCELERATION?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the area doesn't change and do not become narrower, and that the pipe is oriented horizontally, the Bernoulli equation becomes: $P_2 - P_1 = \frac{\rho}{2}(v_1^2 - v_2^2)$. If a fluid accelerates, then $v_1^2 - v_2^2$ will be lowered, so the difference of pressure will be lowered. You are turning piezo (pressure) energy into kinetic energy. 
However, by conservation of mass, since the flow rate is constant because we are in a stationary flow, then speed cannot change. So the Bernoulli equation doesn't hold. We need to introduce the extended Bernoulli equation that takes into account the head loss. The head loss is responsible for the "pressure decreasing" along the axis of the pipe.

The effect you described typically what is used in nozzle in turboreactors with two differences: in nozzles, the area changes, and in nozzles, you use a tiny bit of the internal energy in addition with the piezo energy.

Comment: Bernoulli equation suppose a stationnary incompressible flow. If the area do not change, conservation of mass impose that the speed cannot change in such a stationnary flow ?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli That is a correct observation. I am going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the fluid accelerates due to pressure difference then it will move into lower pressure. Thus the pressure will decrease during the acceleration.

The above is not totally true. The fluid might accelerate side-wise and follow a circle. Then the pressure will not decrease.

We might also have a deceleration, i.e. "negative acceleration". In that case the fluid is moving into higher pressure, so the pressure actually increases.